# What does 鏡越し mean in this sentence?

Tags: translation

I encountered the word 「鏡越し」 while I'm reading a web novel, titled 『とある殉教者の訃報』by 鼠色猫／長月達平

Here is the full sentence.

> 「もし、これが**鏡越しの**会話じゃなかったら、今頃、君はバラバラだったよ。そうならなかったことを、僕に感謝した方がいいんじゃないかな」

I googled 「鏡越し」 and still I couldn't find the meaning of this word. The closet meaning I got when I used google translate was "Glanced up from glasses" and I don't think it is the right translation for this sentence. 
How should it be translated?
Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: related: http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/40876/1628

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like "through the looking glass" or "through the mirror". 
(Which I think may refers to an alternate world/universe/timeline used as a metaphor to illustrate what the present time might have been under different circumstances)

Unless if it happens that in the setting of the story the mirror is a plot device for actually going into an alternate world or communicating to the alternate world (or going/communicating to somewhere else within the same world) then it's not a metaphor.

Comment: Thanks for your help! So should I translate that sentence this way? "If this conversation took place under different circumstance, you will be in pieces by now".

Comment: ＠Lucy I'm assuming there's some sort of mirror in the scene (used as the medium of communication between the two worlds), and you probably shouldn't exclude that in your translation. I'd say the first part would be "If we weren't talking through mirrors..."

Comment: Yes, I think this sentence is actually about something like [magic mirror](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_Mirror_(Snow_White)) in *Snow White*.

Comment: @jimmy ah yes. Apparently, when I read the rest of the novel, it indeed seemed like they are talking through the mirror. At one point, it include a sentence like "the shattering sound of mirror echoed" so it should really be translated as something mirror related. Thank everyone for your help and clearing my misunderstanding.